# Display all images from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bitmap, blob

I recently made a post asking how to display blobs from a sqlite database but got no replies. After more painstaking hours :( I've finally found an answer that does display the blobs in an image view, however it only displays the last blob in the database.

Is there something wrong with my query/loop? or am I totally wrong?

**Activity Class that displays the blobs**

```
 public class championsActivity extends Activity {


    private Bitmap champions;
    private myDBHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_champions);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.champ_splash);
        db= new myDBHelper(this);
        champions = db.getChamp_splash();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(champions);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        db.close();
    }

}
```

**DBHelper class**

```
public class myDBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "champions.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    public myDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        setForcedUpgrade();
    }

    public Bitmap getChamp_splash() {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        String sqlTables = "Champions";

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ sqlTables;


        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                byte[] blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("champ_splash"));
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);

            }

        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

After going over the answers given I have now added the blobs to an array however I still cannot display them. This is my current code

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> getChamp_splash() {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    String sqlTables = "Champions";
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ sqlTables;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            byte[] blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("champ_splash"));
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
            bitmaps.add(bitmap);
        }
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    return bitmaps;
}




public class championsActivity extends Activity {

private GridView gridView;
private Cursor champions;
private myDBHelper db;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> champ_splash;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_champions);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.champ_splash);
    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.champion_grid);
    db= new myDBHelper(this);
    champ_splash = db.getChamp_splash();
    imageView.setImageBitmap(champ_splash);
    champions = db.getChampions();
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            champions,
            new String[] {"Name"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be doing is storing bitmaps into array, like this:

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap> getChamp_splash() {
    ...
    ...
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                byte[] blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("champ_splash"));
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
                bitmaps.add(bitmap);
            }
    }
    ...
    ...
    return bitmaps;
}
```

and then in your `championsActivity`:

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> champions;
private GridView imageGridview;
...
...
imageGridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.my_grid_view);
champions = db.getChamp_splash();
if (champions != null) {  // if the bitmaps were found
    ImageGridViewAdapter adapter = new ImageGridViewAdapter(this, bitmaps, columnWidth);   // using custom adapter for showing images
    // columnWidth is just some int value representing image width
    imageGridview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and the `ImageGridViewAdapter`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
    private int imageWidth;

    public ImageGridViewAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitm, int width) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.bitmaps = bitm;
        this.imageWidth = width;
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return bitmaps.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return bitmaps.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        } 
        else 
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth, imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));

        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Of course, this is displaying images into a `GridView`, if you want to display images differently, then you have to change the adapter.

P.S: I currently cannot test this if it's working perfectly, but this is how I displayed an array of bitmaps in a grid in one of my previous projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @miselkingThankyou for your input, I've followed your answer through and implemented what I can, However there is an error. The line imageGridview.setAdapter(adapter); in champions activity. Is there a way of displaying them using the array but not using a custom adapter? more as simple as possible

Comment: Take it youve gone :( im trying to display the bitmap array in my imageView

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't around, hmm, an ImageView can only show one image. So, the best way to show images is to use adapter (in my case `ImageGridViewAdapter`. Yes, the `imageGridview` variable is of `GridView` type, just like you used it in your edit.As for the updated question, the problem is that `simple_list_item_1` cannot display images, because it only contains a `TextView` in its xml (you can find more about default layouts and how are they implemented [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/layout).
So, what you need to do is to use a custom adapter

Comment: In the end, you need to create a custom adapter to show complex stuff (like images), but you are not limited on showing images in the `GridView`, you can also use `ListView` if you want, you just need some minor tweaks... Or, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548732/listactivity-custom-row-layout-with-bitmap-not-populating-correctly) question (it is also answered in the question), this may be the easiest way to display images (the question contains all the .xml files and java files that you need). Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this is what you programmed in your code - return last image. Code with some comments:

```
// create bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        String sqlTables = "Champions";

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ sqlTables;


        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c != null) {
// go through the result
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                byte[] blob = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("champ_splash"));
// assign each value to bitmap - not very useful as on next iteration - previous bitmap will be overriden
// on last iteration - set to bitmap last item  - all previous will be deleted
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);

            } 

        } 
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        return bitmap;
```

If you want to retrieve collection of objects - return collection of objects.

Comment: I understand your answer but don't know how to code it to return a collection. Sorry I'm very beginner at this, how would I do this?